# How do I use filter() to find age constraints in Python?

Tags: python, filter

**I am trying to use the filter method to compute the median salary for employees with an age greater than 50.**

Here is the data I used to create my data frame,

```
SID = np.array([6893 , 4198 , 6265 , 4900 , 6704 , 9109 , 4528 ,6785 , 3356 , 7469 , 1434 , 8219 , 1207 , 2362 , 3542 ,1277 , 9538,7313,9064,4725,2103,7076,9743,5148,4771,6096,1088] , dtype = 'int32')
Gender = np.array([ 'F ' , 'F ' , 'M ' , 'F ' , 'M ' , 'F ' , 'F ' , 'M ' ,'F ' , 'F ' , 'F ' , 'M ' , 'M ' , 'F ' , 'F ' , 'F ' , 'M ','M ','M ', 'F ','M ','M ','F ','M ','M ','F ','F '])
Age = np.array([23 , 57 , 43 , 54 , 44 , 53 , 24 , 44 , 57 , 54 , 67 ,22 , 60 , 55 , 42 , 37 , 43,62,35,23,33,54,43,59,64,27,56] , dtype = 'int32')
Department = np.array ([ 'Mar' , 'Res' , 'Mar' , 'Mar' , 'Res' ,'Res' , 'Man' , 'Res' , 'Man' , 'Man' , 'Res' , 'Mar' ,'Man' , 'Man' , 'Res' , 'Mar' , 'Man','Man','Mar','Res','Mar','Mar','Res','Res','Man','Man','Res' ])
Salary = np.array ([57126.33 , 43911.31 , 48624.71 ,54350.30 , 35071.43 , 47676.86 , 42470.49 ,52408.86 , 35537.07 , 46918.93 , 50906.68 ,48797.58 , 45230.00 , 44164.64 , 48144.46 ,49506.02 , 54627.42,59909.78,49802.22,55224.95,46075.63,43206.42,39168.57,42171.72,60375.02,66510.43,43423.36] , dtype = 'float64')
Survey = pd.DataFrame ( dict ( SID = SID , Gender = Gender , Age = Age ,Department = Department , Salary = Salary ))
```

I was focusing first on filtering the age to just give me people older than 50, which is below. However, this code does not work.

```
def fun(x):
    return x['Age'] > 50

filter(fun,Survey)
```

I have no idea where to go from here. I do know that `Survey['Salary'].median()` will give me the median salary, but it would include salaries from people who are under 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the record with age > 50,

if so, here is my solution:

`Survey.loc[Survey['age'] > 50].median()`

This will give you all the median information.

And by adding the column name after the condition, it will give you the median value for specific column.

Like this
`Survey.loc[Survey['age'] > 50, 'Salary'].median()`, it will give you the Salary median with Age > 50.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the filter() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
Survey[Survey['Age'] > 50].median()

SID        4771.0
Age          57.0
Salary    45230.0
```

If you really want to use the filter function, what I wouldn't recommend, you can use this:

```
from statistics import median
median50 = median(list(filter(lambda x: x > 50, Survey['Age'])))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the filter() function?

Comment: @CynicalF I don't think so, because the filter function isn't made for that. [Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CynicalF I edited my answer and added an option using the filter function